# Squish for QT » Python: Squish script should continue after AUT was closed

Tags: python, qt, squish

we are using Squish for QT for automating test cases in our project. For a specific test case the AUT (Application Under Test) will be closed to perform an update.

Short information about the test case:

==Start==

1. AUT opens
2. Open the download page
3. Select different items from the download page
4. Select button 
   --> AUT will be closed automatically and "Update"-Application appears.
5. Navigate through the Download-process.
   --> AUT will be opened again
6. Check if the download was successful and all new components are available.

==End==

My problem is that Squish will automatically stop my script after the AUT was closed (after Step 4).

Does anyone know if it is possible that Squish for QT can handle this "second application" during the update-process?

Thank you  and kind regards!

Felix

Comment: Probably you need to attach to the second `Update` application after closing the main application: https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#attachToApplication-function .

Comment: If i try to attach to this application i am getting the following Script Error:
"Detail RuntimeError: Attaching to AUT 'applicationname' failed: connection to AUT refused."

Answer (score 0):

Squish got changed at some point to allow script execution after the AUT exited, so ensure that you have a recent Squish package.

The Update application and the newly started AUT can probably be hooked up again:

- On Windows they need to be started via dllpreload.exe or startaut.exe, or have the attachable Built-in Hook compiled into them ([Using the Built-in Hook](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cppapi.html#rgcpp-qtbuiltin)).
- On Unix sub-process hooking must be enabled in the test suite settings and the environment of the original AUT instance be kept intact, or they need to have the attachable Built-in Hook compiled into them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the built-in hook could not solve the problem :)

Comment: The (Qt) built-in hook works. Something must have gone wrong. Perhaps the Squish "bin" folder is not in PATH? Also, since modifying the application for sake of automation is possible, starting it via dllpreload.exe or startaut.exe should also be possible. I recommend contacting the vendor of Squish.

Comment: Hi frog.ca,
the squis-site says:
"Include the qtbuiltinhook.h header file, which can be found in Squish's include directory, in the application's code(...)"
The problem is that we do not have access to the application source code to include this Hook. We have only access to the Squish Script.
Kind regards
Felix

Comment: Then - as a last resort - it may work to use a Qt plug-in based approach to hook up the unmodified application. I cannot tell if the vendor of Squish has implemented this already. I recommend to contact them to ask about that.